# String with £ symbol returns question black diamond mark PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf, html-entities

I am grabbing meta descriptions from remote urls and when a url contains "£" it returns as a black diamond with a question mark in firefox. When I apply utf8_encode on the string, it returns "£" as it should, however then other UTF characters will not display correctly. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the content type meta tag on the page?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

**Edit**:

To solve what you put in your comment, I might do something like this (super quick and dirty):

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-1374575/Under-18s-sunbed-ban-cut-skin-cancer-toll.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('/(<meta[^\n]+)(name=\"description\"[^\n])(content=\")([^\n]+)(\")/', $data, $m);
echo urlencode($m[4]);

?>
```

Having said that, the *correct* way of doing this would be to parse the HTML returned by the `curl_exec`, find the appropriate node (with `name="description"`) and return the `urlencode`d value of the `content` attribute

Comment: Yes it is set to UTF-8. When I do not apply anything the string returns properly encoding UTF-8 characters except the pound sign

Comment: Have you tried HTML encoding it? The code for that character is &#163;

Comment: How can I properly retrieve meta descriptions from these sites:
`http://cn.atpworldtour.com/Tennis/Tournaments/London-Finals.aspx`
`http://pravda.ru`
`http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-1374575/Under-18s-sunbed-ban-cut-skin-cancer-toll.html`

While keeping the format of the characters